# Unsupervised Anomaly Detection Threshold Selection

Tags: machine-learning, classification, threshold, anomaly-detection

If we have a data set that contains only positive examples I am wondering how we can effectively choose a threshold for an anomaly detection technique. Are there anomaly detection techniques that can select an appropriate threshold given only positive data such that it can reliably identify non-genuine data?